How i can get with ffi luajit discord user id
hello im trying to retrive discord user id like from discord.exe the discord user id with ffi luajit , i found some similar thing in fivem lua
server.lua
local discord = ""
local id = ""
    
identifiers = GetNumPlayerIdentifiers(source)
for i = 0, identifiers + 1 do
    if GetPlayerIdentifier(source, i) ~= nil then
        if string.match(GetPlayerIdentifier(source, i), "discord") then
            discord = GetPlayerIdentifier(source, i)
            id = string.sub(discord, 9, -1)
        end
    end
end

fxmanifest.lua
fx_version 'bodacious'
game 'gta5'

client_scripts {
    'server.lua',
}

